# yii framework - jquery datepicker dont work when i enable ClientValidation in form

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, yii

I m developing a application using yii framework .My one of form requires a yii Client Validation and jquery date picker as well but when i enable my Client Validation jquery date picker stops working .

Following js file are included on a page :

//jquery library

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

//for jquery date picker

"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" 
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"

Comment: i get this error in console $("#inputid").datepicker is not a function

Comment: Are you manually including any js files? Yii usually handles them, even for extensions.

Comment: yes i m manually including these js files. You mean to say that yii automatically includes jquery files ? can you plz explain how ?

Comment: Yes, modules/extensions are written like that. For instance, if you open up CJuiDatePicker.php from framework/zii/widgets/jui and look for the run() method, you can see for yourself that the registerScriptFile method is called multiple times. That handles the inclusion of jquery and jquery ui js files.

Comment: @Örs thank u very munch i was not aware of that...that will help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use CJuiDatePicker instead of loading external jquery-ui:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'model_date',
    // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
    'options'=>array(
        'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'id' => 'foo',
    ),
));
```